# Best practice for passing actual user names from ASP.Net to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am looking for a best pratice to use the actual username in tSQL, while at the same time, my ASP.Net application logs into SQL Server with a global login, configured in the connection string in the web.config file.

This ASP.Net application is written as an extension to a SharePoint2007 implementation. The database this applies to is a legacy database, not a SharePoint database.

The application in question needs to log each insert, update and delete in audit (shadow) tables, including date&time and username. This is done by triggers.

The triggers use the SYSTEM_USER value, so that the global login is always written to the audit table.

There are about 2700 stored procedures in the system, and I guess that half of them perform DML statements.

What would be the best way to change the application so that the actual username is logged? My ASP.Net application knows the usernames. In fact, all of my users log in to the ASP.Net application with an Active Directory account.

I am considering the following options:

1. Use integrated security; but what about permissions that should only be granted throught the application, not to be used when connection with some other SQL client?
2. Set some global variable on each connection that is opened; but in the current code, each requests opens many connections, sometimes hundreds of them, to process the request.
3. Passing the username in the stored procedures, adding a field to each table. The trigger than simply reads the usernames from the tables in stead of deriving it; however, this requires a lot of modifications in database objects, potentially generating a lot of bugs.

Any comments on these options or perhaps other options to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use context info. Integrated security with impersonation will defeat connection pooling and passing username to procs just feels plain wrong.

Comment: It took me a while to understand that context info referred to the actual tSQL construct [CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx). This looks like a good solution.